# use A Search Bar to Search in list of widgets (Button) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Great day

me want to add a Search Bar to Search in list of Widget ( Button ) and made the results shown as a list

my list of button , each button a specific job ( DO Something ) and  a child (Text) so me want to search according to the text in the child widget

this is my button widget

```
Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
child: Material(
  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
  borderRadius: cyrcil,
  elevation: 5.0,
  child: MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {
      routePush(Aqobat(), RouterType.scale);
    },
    minWidth: 50.0,
    height: 42.0,
    child: Text(
      'قانون العقوبات',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: xstyle,
    ),
  ),
),),
```

thx

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Where is your list builder for the list of buttons?